# How do I scan an array and stop the scan when the number becomes false, and echo what number made the loop false in PHP

Tags: php

Basically I am creating a simple music player in PHP and I am setting the id of each song that is played in an array. I have a script which pulls a random number and plays the song with the corresponding id. I want to make it so that if the song has already played that it wont play again.

Currently I have it generate a random number, and if that number has already been played then it adds 1 to the random number.

The problem is if the number that is the result of adding 1 to the random number, it will then play that song again. I was attempting to store the songs played in an array and just increment the number until it doesn't exist in the array but I am struggling to find a solution to the problem.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("blah blah blah");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['played'])) {
    $_SESSION['played'] = array();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Data") ;
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$numsongs= .20 * $num_rows;
$numsongs=floor($numsongs);

$music = rand(1,$numsongs);
if (in_array($music, $_SESSION['played'])) {$music = $music+1;};

/* goes on to play music below */

$_SESSION['played'][] = $music;
?>
```

I didn't put my whole script in, the script works minus the repeating of songs. I only included a snippet of how I wrote the repeating script to give an idea of how I attempted it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up "shuffle()".

Comment: "The problem is if the number that is the result of adding 1 to the random number, it will then play that song again."
Could u explain it more ??

Comment: Don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for. Shuffle just randomizes the array, I already have that covered. I want it to increment the random number until it isn't in the array and then echo that number.

Comment: @Brandon You're not randomizing the array, you're just picking random items. The difference is that randomizing the array and then successively playing the songs from index 0 to index max ensures that (a) the songs are played in a random order and (b) no song is played twice (which may happen with the other approach unless you add additional logic, which you seem to be struggling with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHAAA!! I figured it out! I ended up using switch() but in a different form.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['played1'])) {
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numsongs; ++$i) {
$_SESSION['played1'][] = $i;}}
shuffle($_SESSION['played1']);
$music1= $_SESSION['played1'][0]; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Data WHERE position = '$music1'") ; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$del_val=$row[position];
if(($key = array_search($del_val, $_SESSION['played1'])) !== false) {
unset($_SESSION['played1'][$key]);}
```

Basically created an array between 1 and 10. Then used switch() to randomize the array. Then picked the first number in the array, used it in mysqli query, and then removed it from the array. Problem Solved!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this...

```
$music = rand(1,$numsongs);
while(in_array($music, $_SESSION['played'])){
     $music = $music+1;
     echo 'in array '.$music;
}
echo 'Not in array '.$music;
```